# Logs are not generated with Log4j and Tomcat 8 and open JDK

Tags: logging, java-8, log4j, tomcat8

I am trying to generate logs with Log4j, Tomcat 8 and OpenJDK 8.

I tried ${catalina.home} and ${catalina.base}

I installed my tomcat using [THIS URL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

But logs are not generated in the logs/ folder.

Currently, I am using below properties for the Log4j

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG ,file ,stdout ,upload

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/filelog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
#log4j.additivity.file=false

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.upload=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.upload.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.upload.File=${catalina.home}/logs/file_upload_log.log
log4j.appender.upload.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.upload.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.upload.Append=true
log4j.appender.upload.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.upload.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}:%L - %m%n
#log4j.additivity.upload=false
```

File to give configuration "/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service" as per below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server - XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -    Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**As per above file CATALINA_HOME should be /opt/tomcat**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please share the path of CATALINA_HOME environment variable  
and on which path are u looking for logs.

Comment: Hi @SnehalPatel, I updated my question please have a look into that.

Comment: If your CATALINA_HOME set to "/opt/tomcat" then check log at "/opt/tomcat/logs" path and make sure that you have started tomcat server.

Comment: @SnehalPatel I checked the logs in the folder it's not generated but other projects logs are generated, the only problem with this projects.

Comment: @SnehalPatel even though it's working in development server with ${catalina.home} but not working in production.

Answer (score 0):

@Pranav Pathak , i guess you'r missing log4j library to add in dependencies of tomcat itself.

Check official docs, [tomcat logging using log4j](http://@Pranav%20Pathak%20,%20i%20guess%20you'r%20missing%20log4j%20library%20to%20add%20in%20dependencies%20of%20tomcat%20itself%20Check%20official%20docs,%20https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html) ,  (Using **log4j** section)